# displayavatarURL when someone joins the server returns always the same error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im trying to make my discord.js bot send an embed when someone joins, with as thumbnail their pfp, but it always leaves the same error.

code:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    // Send the message to a designated channel on a server:
    const WelcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === config.WelcomeChannelVar);
    var newMember = member
    // Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
    if (!WelcomeChannel) return;
    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(newMember + 'joined!')
    .addField('username', member)
    .setColor(0x348a58)
    .setThumbnail(newMember.showAvatarURL())
    .setFooter('wow very nice profile bro')
    WelcomeChannel.send(welcomeEmbed);

    member.send("welcome to frogpond! read the rules :)");
});
```

error:

```
TypeError: newMember.showAvatarURL is not a function
```

I've tried everything. can somebody help plz?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that showAvatarURL() is not a function and you mean avatarURL() instead, so you should change your code to be like this:

```
const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
// your stuff before thumbnail
.setThumbnail(newMember.user.avatarURL())
// your stuff after thumbnail
```

edit: the .user is important, because avatarURL is only a User function

Comment: Yup, I missed that one, thank you for helping them :)

Comment: thanks! one question, if the user doesnt have a pfp, does it show the default or nothing?

Comment: @FrancescoGatta displayAvatarURL() does return the default profile picture if the user does not have one, as described [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you wrote `showAvatarURL()` instead of `displayAvatarURL()`.

Comment: @FrancescoGatta The exact same one ?

Comment: @FrancescoGatta If you changed the `.setThumbnail(newMember.showAvatarURL())` to `.setThumbnail(newMember.displayAvatarURL())` then it should not be the exact same error

Comment: TypeError: newMember.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Comment: @FrancescoGatta Then your newMember variable is wrong somewhere